# How to extend my rails app to a native mobile app? API vs normal controller JSON

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, json, api

I've been developing in Android Studio and Xcode for a while... Also Ive been recently developing rails apps. After looking and finishing some tutorials on how to extend my rails app to a native mobile app I have just one doubt.

I'm sure that I understand what an API is, but I'm not sure if the fact of extending a rails app to a native mobile app will need it. Because I can create and respond to JSON without an API in the "original" controller.

What is the differences between creating an API and responding to the JSON in the "original" controller? Give a use case for both of them please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By responding with JSON in your "normal" controller you will be building an API, you don't need the API-only version of rails, or any particular gem to build and API, just an agreed interface (request/responses) for your apps to get all the information you want.

Comment: Thanks man... Soooo... Just for curiosity... Is there a use case where both of this are used? 
I know that "api-only" is pretty clear but sounds like something that can happen...

Comment: If your current controllers, serving JSON are enough, go that route. At some point you might need separate controllers for your JSON API and HTML app (you might recognize this when you start having too many conditionals branching behavior based on the request type).api-only route.

Comment: @LuisLopez Your Rails app can serve two purposes : serve JSON to mobile application AND be a "dashboard" to manage the data (using regular HTML views, like a control panel).

Comment: @MrYoshiji That broadens my view... Don't you know if it's common to take the "JSON with normal controller path?" Will it be difficult to migrate to an API only controller having the normal one setup?

Comment: You might want to split your routes into what is reserved for JSON, ex `/api/v1/*` and the leave the rest unscoped. This way, you will clearly see if a controller is supposed to respond with JSON or serve another purpose